# How to add custom claims from Azure portal application settings

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-authentication

**Background:** I need to integrate azure active directory single-sign-on in my Angular 6 app. It is done well. I get a user object after calling the azure authentication service.

I am using adal-angular4 npm package to achieve this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-angular4

**Problem:** Now, I need to receive some additional fields in the "user" object as a response of Azure authentication. For that I studied the topic of "custom claims".

**Attempts:**
I tried the docs of microsoft related to it but got no success. The following one
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-claims-customization

I need to get the "samAccountName" in the user object as a response of the authentication web call. I added this in the single sign on configuration in the azure portal but still not receiving the mentioned claim.I navigated to
Portal > Azure Active Directory(left hand side) > Enterprise Applications > test_claims_new (my application) > single sign on > Saml

Then, following is the screen shot of my azure app settings.

[image]

[image]

Following is my Angular code to perform the authentication

```
let config = {
    clientId: 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    popUp: true,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',
    callback : (errorDesc, token, error, tokenType) =>
    {
      if(!error){
        console.log("User: " , this.authContext._user);
      }  
    }
  };

  this.authContext = new adalAuthContext(config);
```

Following is the response (user object) I get through this entire code and configurations:

[image]

**Expected Result:**
One of the properties as mentioned in the above azure settings screenshot named `user.onpremisesamaccountname` should appear in my user object but I am not getting it.